# 'If/else' statement inside 'nav' tag

Tags: craft2, comments

Craft CMS V2. 
Comment Plugin: [verbb comment](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments)

```
<ul>
    {% nav comment in comments %}
       {% if comment.isFlagged() == false %}
          <li>
              {% include '_forms/templates/comment-' ~ comment.status %}
              {% include '_forms/templates/form' %}

            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul class="child">
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
          </li>
       {% endif %}
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

The above code creates this error:

```
Unexpected "ifchildren" tag (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag)
```

So, How can I use `if/else` condition inside the `nav` tag to hide flagged comment including it's children.

Comment: Could something along those lines work - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30688/show-only-children-relative-to-current-page/30695#30695 ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it can't be done. I'm not sure why, but it's some sort of conflict with how `nav`, `children`, and `ifchildren` operates.

The workaround is ugly (but it works). Just use two separate, but identical `if` statements... one before the `ifchildren`, and one after.

```
{% if comment.isFlagged() == false %}
    ...
{% endif %}
{% ifchildren %}
    ...
{% endifchildren %}
{% if comment.isFlagged() == false %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:**

If this solution doesn't work for you, I recommend looping over the `comments` array and removing all flagged comments *before* you run it through the `nav` loop.

Comment: This solution is not appropriate in my case because approved child comments of flagged (inappropriate) parent comment shows though the parent flagged (inappropriate) comment has been removed.

Comment: You could potentially repeat the same conditional again _within_ the `ifchildren` tag. If that solution doesn't work for you, you might be out of luck.